# Is there a way to force pandas dataframe query to use 'python' as default engine?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

According to doc, you can do this:

```
df.query(myQuery, engine='python')
```

It happens that 99% of what I did (in a single file or ipython notebook), i will need engine='python', and it gets really tiresome to be reminded of, and typing that extra arg. Is there a global config I can use to just set this as default? I would prefer first not to do my own custom override, if there's a library provided way to do this.

Addendum:

A potential ans to this question is posted from Sebastian. It looks good but on further usage, I found there's a hiccup. This makes me think such override/custom is a bit invasive and what I had wanted to avoid in the first place (thus posting the question for a global option supported by Pandas).

```
from functools import partialmethod
pd.DataFrame.query = partialmethod(pd.DataFrame.query, engine="python")

x = ['abc', 'cdf', '123']
df.query("myColValue.isin(@x)")
```

This will filter out any myColValue that contains any one element of x. This works on first trial. But if you happen to run the .query partialmethod override twice, it will break. Running things twice is not so infrequent. E.g. when you rerun notebook cells, or possible the code is present >1 file and imported >1 times. I think even if you monkey this further to make such scenario works, the solution may not be worth it. it may be ok if you are a solo developer without a larger code base to maintain.

Comment: Changing the source code?

Comment: write a wrapper: `def query(df, myQuery): return df.query(myQuery, engine='python')` :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang In my opinion, this is not the most ideal, it destroyed the OO aspect of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem like that is an [available option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options) provided by pandas.

You can make a workaround though by using the [`functools.partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod)-function. `partialmethod` can bind positional- or keyword-arguments to functions, so all you need to do is bind `engine="python"` to `pd.DataFrame.query` and assign it back to `pd.DataFrame.query`. Essentially overwriting `pd.DataFrame.query` with an identical function that has `engine="python"` bound to it:

```py
from functools import partialmethod
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.query = partialmethod(pd.DataFrame.query, engine="python")

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.query(myQuery) # The argument `engine="python"` is already bound
```

In case you would want this to be a temporary change, you can store a reference to the original method and assign it back when you are done:

```py
from functools import partialmethod
import pandas as pd

original_query = pd.DataFrame.query
pd.DataFrame.query = partialmethod(pd.DataFrame.query, engine="python")

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.query(myQuery) # The argument `engine="python"` is already bound

...

pd.DataFrame.query = original_query
```

If anyone else is importing your module you should probably do this to to avoid polluting their `pandas`-import.

Comment: This may do for me. Is there a good way to scope this? my only concern is monkeying around standard API is not a good idea as your code base grows.

Comment: Also, what happen if i call df.query(myQuery, engine='other stuff'), would this keep working? sorry for being unfamiliar with partial method, but will try. This won't be a good solution if it doesn't work. I want other ppl working with the code to be able to specific their engine, just that the default is changed to 'python'

Comment: Update: i think this is the next best solution so far given there's no global option to change that default from Pandas.

Comment: This solution is not good. I found it breaks local var binding, and can't use df.query("aColumn.isin(@x)").

Comment: @kawingkelvin Using `partialmethod(pd.DataFrame.query, engine="python")` can indeed be compared to setting a new default value for the method, since the `engine` parameter in `df.query(myQuery, engine='other stuff')` will still be passed through to the original `df.query`. I tried to answer your other comments by updating my answer. Can you elaborate on your comment stating that the solution "breaks local var binding"?

Comment: I think I will put the snippet and explanation in the question itself. @Sebasian

Comment: Pls review my addendum. I think I can still accept your ans., provided you mentioned all these caveats, just want others to be warned. The real quick sweat ans could simply be "there's no globally option you can override that is supported by Pandas", and i would be ok. All other workaround that override is not in the scope of my original question.

Comment: @kawingkelvin These are some very good points, and reading your addendum I agree with you that the solution proposed in this answer is probably too invasive in a shared codebase.

Comment: I think it will be safer if instead of overwriting .query, a new obj method name is to be binded: pd.DataFrame.q_py = partialmethod(pd.DataFrame.query, engine="python"), does partial method allow this?